# how to use same color intervals for different spplots in R

Tags: r

I have interpolated maps of temperature data of different days, such like:

[image: 2 interpolated maps(left: January, right: July]

I want to show the maps of different days side by side, but would like to have the same color ramps and intervals in the legendary for both. 
The maximum temperature value is: 29.8
min: -13.4

I did try to use the Answer from [How to use the same color scale for points in different maps in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101382/how-to-use-the-same-color-scale-for-points-in-different-maps-in-r/21103053#21103053) but I did get an error by doing so:

```
maxim <- 30
minim <- -14
cuts <- 2*(-7:15)
p1 <- spplot(idw_ger, "var1.pred", main="IDW January, 10", cuts=cuts, col.regions=bpy.colors(30)) +
latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(ger, fill = NA, col = 'blue')) +
latticeExtra::layer(sp.points(tdata,
                            fill = NA, col = 'black'))
```

*Error in seq.default(zrng[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvO4I.png), zrng[2], length.out = cuts + 2) : 
  length must be non-negative number
In addition: Warning message:
In seq.default(zrng[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvO4I.png), zrng[2], length.out = cuts + 2) :
  first element used of 'length.out' argument*

What am I doing wrong and how can I bring it to work?

Comment: From ?spplot:" `cuts`: number of cuts, or, for objects of class SpatialPointsDataFrame only, the actual cuts to use. " I think your error is related to this. Try changing `cuts` to a single value, i.e. the number of cuts you need. What does that give you?

Comment: If I use cuts=20 in both of the spplot() methods for the different days, I do get 20 intervals in both, but they are not covering the same range, e.g. january -6 to +8 with ~0.3 intervals and july 4 to 16 with ~0.25 intervals

Comment: `zlim` should work in `spplot` similarly to the  answer from @koekenbakker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that precise `cuts` can only be specified for SpatialPointsDataFrame, I think you need to use an alternative for `spplot`. Here's an example using `image` and `image.plot` for the legend (adapted from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2007-June/002143.html). By setting the upper and lower limit of the data (`zlim`), you can create two identical colour ramps. Just replace `zinc.idw` and `copper.idw` with your own data.

Load data:

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(fields)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
data(meuse.grid)
coordinates(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
gridded(meuse.grid) = TRUE
```

Create two IDW grids:

```
zinc.idw = krige(zinc~1, meuse, meuse.grid)
copper.idw = krige(copper~1, meuse, meuse.grid)
```

Set up plot:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2),oma=c(2,2,2,2))
cols = bpy.colors(30)
zmin = 0
zmax = 1000
```

Plot map and measurement locations:

```
image(zinc.idw, zlim=c(zmin,zmax),col=cols)
box()
mtext(side=3,text='zinc')
points(meuse, pch = 3)
```

Add legend:

```
image.plot( zlim=c(zmin,zmax), nlevel=5,legend.only=TRUE, horizontal=F, col=cols)
```

Same for other copper grid;

```
image(copper.idw, zlim=c(zmin,zmax),col=cols)
box()
mtext(side=3,text='copper')
points(meuse, pch = 3)
image.plot( zlim=c(zmin,zmax), nlevel=5,legend.only=TRUE, horizontal=F, col=cols)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Unfortunately the maps lose their expressiveness since both maps only have values of a small subinterval of the entire color ramp :/ I would like to try it again without the bpy color values. Do you know how I can give it a 2color ramp from dark blue (low values) to light yellow (high values)?

Comment: That's a different question. See `?colorRamp`. Example: `cols=colorRampPalette(c("darkblue","yellow"))(10); A = matrix(rep(1:10,2),ncol=2,nrow=10); image(A,col=cols)`. Good enough? Then use that `cols` for your plots.